How to sort the result of a Search Kit?
I have a multi record date custom field related to contact.
When I view the result of the submission of the custom field in search kit the result shows in random order. How do I sort in Ascending/Descending order by default?
Thanks

are you on latest SK?

Pradeep's answer is correct about where the sort option is, but I'm confused about what you're asking since it's a multivalued date field - what does sorting mean for a multivalued field?

You will need to create it as a display and add sorting criteria.

